# What does the C* (Cstar) parameter demand ?(A320)

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-controls, airbus, theory, fly-by-wire

I have been reading a LOT of research papers and many articles, but none of them tell how the C* parameter in Airbus is used for the vertical augmentation of the aircraft.

I am aware that with a deflection in sidestick, a G-load is demanded through a COM channel
{(-1,+2.5) -> in clean config} but I have many questions :

1. What is the relation of this G-load demand with the Load factor(Nz) and C* ?
2. I know that C* = Nz + (Vco * Q)/g, where Vco for A320 is 210 knots, how is this computed C* parameter used ?
3. What is the final parameter that can be used for demanding an elevator deflection through a controller?
4. What control structure lies between the G-load demand and the final elevator deflection?
   I want to know the proper Math behind it.

Many people have no idea about all this and keep spreading misinformation on various platforms because of which I got extremely deviated from the right information so I am here asking these questions :)

Thank you

Comment: > "I am aware that with a deflection in sidestick, a G-load is demanded [...]"

Not exactly. A C* is demanded, not G-load. A given deflection of the sidestick corresponds to a C* demand. Then the controller simply targets that C* demand. Answer to questions 3 and 4 probably involves airbus proprietary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C* is easier to understand if you start with pure g-force control. The basic components are:

- The control stick, where the pilot commands a load factor in the -1.0 to 2.5 range.
- The accelerometer, which measures the actual load factor in the body-z-direction.
- A PID controller, which controls elevator deflection so that measured load factor always matches the pilot's command. The P, I, and D gains in this controller are not considered part of the C* law and must be tuned for a specific airframe.

When we go from g-force control to C*, we replace the feedback source of the PID controller with a calculated value C*:

$$ C^* = n_z + \frac{v_{co}}{g} \dot\theta$$

This "fake load factor" C* has the same units (none) as the measured load factor it replaced. It goes into the feedback input of the PID controller. The command input of the PID controller (from the pilot via control stick) remains unchanged.

$n_z$ is the measured load factor, $v_{co}$ is crossover speed in meters per second and $\dot\theta$ is pitch rate in radians per second. $g$ is specific gravity in meters per second squared, as usual. The second part of the formula is basically "what would be the centrifugal force if the aircraft was traveling at crossover speed." We add this value to our fake load factor regardless of actual speed.

As to why this setup was chosen, consider pure g-force control again. If the pilot pulled on the stick at low airspeed, the PID controller would yank the elevator to full deflection and point the aircraft's nose vertically into the sky in a desperate attempt to get more g-forces than physically possible. By adding a fake feedback term based on pitch rate, we appease the PID controller. From the PID's point of view, the aircraft now handles as if it was always flying at crossover speed or faster; always responding to more elevator deflection with more g-forces. This removes the incentive to pull as hard as possible as fast as possible.